# How to completely remove a merged pull request?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I merged a pull request on GitHub. However, it was a mistake, and I want to undo the merge, its commits, and most importantly, delete all the files introduced by these several commits from the history.

I reverted the commit with another one and it works, but the files are still in the commit history (they're big) and it would be nice if the commits themselves disappeared.

I've tried to filter-branch removing the files, but it doesn't seem to be shrinking the repository size (and the commits are still there).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tree-filter or index-filter didn't work. Hard resetting and repacking didn't either.

Here's what worked:

`git checkout <commit>`

`git push --force origin HEAD:master`

Now I'm curious as to why those solutions didn't work. I was checking using the size-pack in `git count-objects -v`. Is this correct? Should I see a reduction in size right away or only after pushing to origin?

Answer (score 6):

Remove the merge and the commits with

```
git reset --hard <sha1>
```

as described by @knittl. However, you won't see any change in your repository size until you delete the associated dangling objects. You also need to expire the reflog from keeping a reference to those objects with e.g.

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git prune
git repack -a -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverting the commit will not remove the files from history.

If you want the files not only to not exist in the current HEAD, but also to *never have existed at all*, `git revert` isn't the right command for you. You need to run a `filter-branch` to remove those files completely.

You said you've already done this, but you don't show us how; if you correctly do the following:

- `git filter-branch --tree-filter` to remove the files
- `git reflog expire --expire={1 second}`
- `rm -rf .git/refs/original`
- `git gc`

... **then** repository should shrink. You need the last three steps because (in order):

- The original commits are reachable via your reflog
- References to the original commits are stored by `filter-branch` in `refs/original`
- Until you run a garbage collection, the "loose" objects aren't deleted

Comment: I want to remove a folder. I tried:
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch badFolder'; git reflog expire --expire=now; rm -rf .git/refs/original; git gc; // And then: git count-objects -v; But the size-pack didn't go down.

Comment: @Allan If you're using that `git rm` command, you probably want `git filter-branch --index-filter` rather than `git filter-branch --tree-filter`.

Comment: @Borealid Your solution still has a couple holes - use `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` to clean all reflogs (each branch has a reflog and there may still be pointers in a different branch), and instead of `git gc`, run `git repack -Ad; git prune --expire=now` (`git gc` won't remove dangling objects from existing pack files, `repack` is necessary for that).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the merge and it's associated commits, use `git reset --hard`:

```
git reset --hard <commit before merge>
```

Note that this will destroy any uncommitted changes in your current HEAD. It will also remove all commits that happened after the merge (so maybe you are better off using git rebase).

After resetting your branch, force-push it to make the new history persistent.

**DISCLAIMER**: It's bad practice to rewrite already published history. Don't do this, if you don't have to.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to :(

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the best way is to use Git Reflog:

```
git reflog
```

Check which point is the best for you and move there:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{124}
```

Then, Force Push